# Having trouble with java import statement, bad class file contains wrong class

Tags: java, import

Getting error on my import statement, have this class file set up the same way as rest of all other classes, but only this one seems to be giving an error.

File setup is as follows:

```
a1/sensors/omnitemp/OmniTempSensorX3.class
  /oldtempinc/hardware/OldSensorDevice.class
  /OldTempSensorAdapter.java
  /OldSensorDevice.class
```

Error Message:

```
cannot access itec3030.assignments.a1.oldtempinc.hardware.OldSensorDevice
bad class file: C:\Users\Desktop\York\Winter 2021\itec3030\assignments\a1\oldtempinc\hardware\OldSensorDevice.class
class file contains wrong class: oldtempinc.hardware.OldSensorDevice
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

[This is the line the error is on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RcvM.png)

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It's expecting to find the class `itec3030.assignments.a1.oldtempinc.hardware.OldSensorDevice`. But the class in that file instead was `oldtempinc.hardware.OldSensorDevice`. You could modify the runtime classpath, or change the package name of that class.

Comment: seems, you are new to java :), best would be if you began with an IDE such as Eclipse or IntelliJ (just google it). Those IDEs can help you figure out those errors avoid them.